# How does sphinx UTF-8 search work?

Tags: php, utf-8, sphinx

In my database I have Unicode characters like `再也` encoded in UTF-8.

When I use sphinx search, I am not able to find that particular word. I tried searching using the HTML encoded `&#20877;&#20063;` which did not work as well.

The charset type in my sphinx.conf is:

```
    charset_type = utf-8
```

Any idea how to make sphinx search for UTF-8 characters? I'm clueless.

Comment: Are you sending your search in UTF-8 as well?

Comment: Sphinx supports UTF-8, but you need to define which characters are part of a word as well. Otherwise those characters don't get indexed. See: http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/manual-0.9.9.html#charsets

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with Chinese full-text searching, you can try this: http://code.google.com/p/sphinx-for-chinese