# Sphinx. Ignore non english chars

Tags: php, sphinx

We are using sphinx as our full-text search server and we have a problem. Our language contains letters such as ą, č, ę etc... .

So if I search for 'ąbč' I get results only for 'ąbč', how I could solve this that I get results for 'abc' as well and if I search for 'abc' I get results for 'ąbč' .

Thank you.

Comment: Read about `charset_type` and `charset_table` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6689611/how-does-sphinx-utf-8-search-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added charset_table, works like a charm.

```
charset_table       =\
    0..9,A..Z->a..z,a..z,\
    U+104->a,U+10C->c,U+116->e,U+118->e,U+12E->i,\
    U+160->s,U+172->u,U+16A->u,U+17D->z,U+105->a,U+10D->c,U+117->e,U+119->e,\
    U+12F->i,U+161->s,U+173->u,U+16B->u,U+17E->z
```

Thanks for the link